# Copy Worksheet from another workbook INTO Worksheet of active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which is supposed to import the sheet "aktueller Stand" from an other workbook. This sheet is then copied to the workbook (the one I want to import stuff to) after the sheet "Tabelle 2". So far so good:

```
Option Explicit
 Public Sub WOBImport()
        Dim sFileName As String
        Dim targetSht As Worksheet

        Set targetSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle2")


        sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsx")

        Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
            If sFileName <> targetSht.Parent.Name Then
                On Error Resume Next
                With Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
                    .Sheets("aktueller Stand").Copy After:=targetSht
                    .Close False
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            sFileName = ""
        Loop
    End Sub´
```

How can I manage, that the Sheet "aktueller Stand" ist **not copied AFTER** the position of sheet "Tabelle 2" (`.Sheets("aktueller Stand").Copy After:=targetSht`) **but INTO it**. (So that the data in Tabelle 2 is replaced by the copied data of "aktueller Stand").

I tried:

```
 .Sheets("aktueller Stand").Copy Destination:=targetSht
```

but that does not seem to work.

thanks so much in advance!

Seb

Comment: What you're doing is copying a spreadsheet (`...Sheets.copy`). Instead, you need to copy the range in the `aktueller Stand` sheet (`Sheets("aktueller Stand").Range([something]).Copy`), and paste to a range in `targetSht`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I tried this ```.Sheets("aktueller Stand").Range(A1, H8).Copy Destination:=targetSht.Range(A1, H8).``` but it wont paste it..

Comment: Put the Ranges in quotes: `.Sheets("aktueller Stand").Range("A1, H8").Copy Destination:=targetSht.Range("A1, H8").` (Note this selects each cell individually, for the inclusive range, `...Range("A1:H8")...`)

Comment: Works!! *-* Thank you so much for this detailed advice! :)
Is it also possible to select the cells like e.g. (A1:"every cell that contains data")? Basically I want to select all cells that have data in them.

Comment: I did this ```.Sheets("aktueller Stand").Cells.Copy Destination:=targetSht.Cells``` and seems to work :)

Comment: Note that `Worksheets().Cells()` uses *every single cell*.